# How to group by a dataframe and concatenate by a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with the following structure:

| Store | Sku | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 20 |
| 2 | A | 20 |
| 1 | B | 10 |
| 2 | B | 25 |

And I have to transform it, so that the stores with the same sku and same value, end up concatenated in a cell with a "-" separator like the following.

| Store | Sku | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 - 2 | A | 20 |
| 1 | B | 10 |
| 2 | B | 25 |

How can I approach this?

Comment: @It_is_Chris I'm grouping by sku and value, if a value is different, then it should go in another line. And the store column should by a concatenation of al the stores sharing the same sku and value separated by a "-".

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. Just convert to store column to a string `df['Store'] = df['Store'].astype(str)` then groupby: `df.groupby(['Sku', 'Value'])['Store'].agg(' - '.join).reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby the sku and value and then list the store

```
df.groupby(['Sku','Value'])['Store'].apply(list).reset_index()
```